# nrf24l01 radio chip seems to return incorrect bytes - am I even talking to the device or I'm just getting pre-existing bytes in SPI_DR?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded, wireless

So I am running into this issue where I try to read something off the radio module but I keep getting the same value, which is `0x1C`, and I have no idea why 0x1C in particular.

[NRF24L01](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/nRF24L01_prelim_prod_spec_1_2.pdf) is the radio module I'm using. To do initial testing, I sent `0xff` which denotes the status register and I should be receiving `0xE` which is the reset value of the register.

Following is how I am configuring the SPI peripheral:

```
// main.c

nrfl2401 nrfRadio;

void nRF24_GPIO_Init(void)
{
    // configure CE and SCN
    GPIO_InitTypeDef gpioPort;
    gpioPort.Pin = rNRF24_CE_PIN;
    gpioPort.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    gpioPort.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    gpioPort.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;

    HAL_GPIO_Init(nRF24_GPIO_PORT, &gpioPort);
    RESET_CE();

    gpioPort.Pin = rNRF24_CSN_PIN;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(nRF24_GPIO_PORT, &gpioPort);
    SET_CSN();

    // configure SCK
    gpioPort.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    gpioPort.Pin = SPI_SCLK_PIN;
    gpioPort.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(SPI_SCLK_PORT, &gpioPort);

    // configure MOSI
    gpioPort.Pin = SPI_MOSI_PIN;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(SPI_MOSI_PORT, &gpioPort);

    // configure MISO
    gpioPort.Pin = SPI_MISO_PIN;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(SPI_MISO_PORT, &gpioPort);
}

void SPI_Init(SPI_InitTypeDef *SPI_Config, SPI_TypeDef *SPIx)
{
    SPI_handle.Instance = SPIx;
    SPI_handle.Init = *SPI_Config;

    __HAL_RCC_SPI2_CLK_ENABLE();
    HAL_SPI_Init(&SPI_handle);
}

void nRF24_Init(nrfl2401_Config *radioConfig)
{
    nRF24_GPIO_Init();
    nrfRadio.config = *radioConfig;
    nRF24_Initialization(&nrfRadio);
}

int main(void) {
   // ...
   SPI_InitTypeDef spi_config = {
            Mode: SPI_MODE_MASTER,
            Direction: SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES,    
            DataSize: SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT,
            CLKPolarity: SPI_POLARITY_LOW,
            CLKPhase: SPI_PHASE_1EDGE,
            NSS: SPI_NSS_SOFT,
            BaudRatePrescaler: SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_8, 
            FirstBit: SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB,
            TIMode: SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE,
            CRCCalculation: SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE,
            CRCPolynomial: 7
    };
    SPI_Init(&spi_config, SPI2);

    nrfl2401_Config radioConfig = {
            spiHandle: &SPI_handle
    };
    nRF24_Init(&radioConfig);
    
    while (1);
}

// radio.c
void nRF24_SendCommand(nrfl2401 *nrf, uint8_t *txBuffer, uint8_t *rxBuffer, uint8_t size)
{
    RESET_CSN();  // disable chip select
    
    HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_IT(nrf->config.spiHandle, txBuffer, rxBuffer, size);
    while (nrf->config.spiHandle->State != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);
    
    ENABLE_CSN(); // enable chip select
}

void nRF24_ReadStatusRegister(nrfl2401 *nrf)
{
    uint8_t txBuffer[1] = {nRF24_CMD_NOP};
    uint8_t rxBuffer[1] = {0};
    nRF24_SendCommand(nrf, txBuffer, rxBuffer, (uint8_t) 1);

    while(1);
}

void nRF24_Initialization(nrfl2401 *nrf)
{
    nRF24_ReadStatusRegister(nrf);
}
```

Here's the output from LA:
The thing that looks suspicious is the early dip in MOSI and SCK signals.
[image]

**NOTE:**

I tried sending the same byte multiple times and saw the expected byte `0xE` in return in all the reads except for the first one (where I receive `0x1C`). Why could that be?

Here's 3 transactions with the `0xE` bytes except for the first one.
[image]

Here's the capture with `CSN` (CH5).
[image]

Comment: Where's your SPI select line?  Also you seem to have one-shot-through code, that's rarely a good idea when debugging, consider making it loop on a read of some useful status register.  Consider digging up some known good code...

Comment: Are you referring to Chip Select? are you saying I should be constantly reading the data off the status register to get a better idea?

Comment: So I tried sending multiple bytes and I get `0xE` in the subsequent reads (after the 1st one). Wonder what's up with the first transaction

Comment: what do you get if you shift 0x0E one bit to left? .... you are dealing with a bit stream .... examine the data in binary notation

Comment: 0x1C but I don’t get the logic...why is there a shift to begin with

Comment: Your chip select is still missing...

Comment: It’s not missing. Check the comment if you couldn’t find where I’m ‘enabling’ CSN

Comment: But that is the problem, you enable it once, you don't use it. The CSpin must be set high after each transaction, and set low before each transaction, otherwise the chip does not know which is the first byte of a transaction.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I added a comment to your 'answer' below...

Comment: Even after all of these edits your logic analyzer trace *still* does not show anything labelled as and being properly utilized as an SPI chip select.  If you insist on being this stubborn you'll just have to solve the problem (which is probably that) on your own.

Comment: i dont have extra female wires to hook up the CS pin to LA. What are you trying to figure out? like i seem to be getting the expected bytes but just not at the first attempt, & i explained that i am disabling CSN before the transaction & enabling right after...

Answer (score 1):

The SPI protocol is incorrect in the usage of Chipselect pin, so it's possible that the chip returns incorrect status byte. The CS pin should idle high, and be set low before performing a transaction on the bus, and set high after it.

It is also important to make sure that the bus signals match the signal diagram in the radio chip datasheet, i.e. the SPI clock must be low when CS is pulled low. So this relationship between SCK and CS was invalid during the first transaction, SCK was high when CS was pulled low so the radio chip could see that as the first rising edge and the rest of the bits are then shifted off by one. 0x1C shifted by one is 0x0E.

Comment: Yeah so when I tried to send multiple transactions with the existing code, I got `0x1C` followed by `0x0` for subsequent transactions. Then I disabled the CS pin prior to sending and set to high after the transaction is done in `nRF24_SendCommand()` and then I got `0x1C` and `0xE` for subsequent transactions. The first part remains consistent...

Comment: Is the logic analyzer set to sync on CS pin as well? Is the logic analyzer set to same SPI mode than what the MCU and radio chip use? Have you got a proper delay between CS low to first byte, and proper delay from last byte to CS high? Have you got proper delay from powerup/unreset to first transaction? If first transaction at init is always bogus, just do one transaction at init and discard result?

Comment: It can't be related to LA since upon putting a breakpoint after the first transaction is done, i see rx buffer has `0x1C` so what I see in LA seems to be legit. There's supposed to be 100ms delay after power up but I already have the device hooked to 3.3V prior to running the program so that's out of question too. But discarding the result of the first transaction doesn't seem like a legit solution but more of just getting around it

Comment: can you rectify your answer cause it isn't one. I have also attached the image with CSN pin

Comment: I will change my answer when it is proven wrong. And it is not proven wrong yet, your new picture only proves your CS usage is still incorrect. You set CS low even before you initialize the SPI bus where the clock goes low. Initialize CS high, then initialize the SPI bus, and for all transactions, even the first one, set CS low first, then transfer data, and then set CS high. The clock should not start from high when CS is already low. Clock must be low before CS is pulled low.

Comment: okay so one thing I noticed was upon GPIO initialization of the pins, SCK didn't go low but others did (MOSI, MISO). After `CSN` was pulled high, MOSI and MISO go up as well. Then comes the transaction: as you can see `nRF24_SendCommand()` in the posted snippet, I pull `CSN` low before calling the HAL function for the transaction and pull `CSN` high right after it's done. The CLK seems to go low after `SPE` is enabled inside `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_IT()` which is after pulling `CSN` low as apparent in the capture...

Comment: Problem might be that you do initalize SPI first and then GPIO as alternate for SPI later, that is the wrong order to do it according to HAL docs. Or do you implement HAL_SPI_MSP_init yourself?

Comment: i'm actually initializing SPI specific GPIOs inside `nRF24_GPIO_Init()` which is called after `SPI_Init()`. Should I move the SPI specific GPIO init to `HAL_SPI_MSP_init()`? In this example code, `nRF24_GPIO_Init()` is done after `SPI_Init()` https://github.com/LonelyWolf/stm32/blob/master/nrf24l01/main.c#L176

Comment: In the code you linked, GPIO pins are first initialized to SPI mode right before the SPI peripheral is initialized. Just like HAL code requires. So the rest of the GPIO pins that are plain GPIO for the chip are initialized later.

Comment: `SPI_Init(&spi_config, SPI2)` which initializes the SPI peripheral is called before `nRF24_Init()` which initializes the SPI-specific GPIO pins (SCK, MOSI, MISO). Is the point we're getting at to ensure SCK is low before CS is pulled low?

Comment: Yes, and currently the problem is that your code violates the requirement of SPI HAL by initializing the SPI peripheral first and the SPI specific GPIO after that. It might be the root cause of the problem that CLK starts at wrong phase for the NRF chip. Or then it is something else.

Comment: hm, okay but what's suspicious is CLK pin being an alternate function reg not resetting to its default value `0x00` after init like other pins do...

Comment: Yes it is suspicious, but anything can happen when things are done in wrong sequence. The logic analyzer can also pull undriven signals high, especially if it is the legacy 8-channel Logic or cheap clone of it.

Comment: I moved the GPIO initialization part to `HAL_SPI_MSP_init()` which happens before the SPI init and still the same issue. As discussed, I think the main issue is SCK remaining high till `SPE` is enabled (which happens inside `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_IT()` over which I have no control...

Comment: Which STM32 this is? Did you enable pull-down on the SCK? Do you have external pull-up/down resistors on the SCK pin?

Comment: It's nucleo F401RE. The mode on SCK is `GPIO_MODE_AF_PP`. and I don't have any external resistors. The SCK pin that i'm using is `PB13`, as shown in the snippet

Comment: Reference manual says the pin state should be set to match the polarity and phase before enabling the peripheral, and if the pin is high then that requirement is violated too. Enable the internal pull-down on PB13, or first initialize it as output low, before setting it to AF_PP mode. Or set SPE manually. Or, just transfer one dummy byte with CS high as a workaround as discussed initially.

Comment: okay enabling the internal pull down worked. but why like other pins SCK wasn't being pulled to 0 upon GPIO init? cause it's alternate function reg?

Comment: Who knows how the MCU works internally. So now that the SPI initializes with correct SCK state, and the CS is set active with correct SCK polarity, does the status register now work on the first transaction? I also have to remember this the next time someone says pull-up or pull-down resistors on SPI bus are not needed.

Comment: So SCK being high when CS was low was an issue considering CPOL=0 meaning the SCK has a low-level idle state and it was high, yeah? i didn't try it but would it have worked fine if CPOL=1? and I asked about SCK not going zero cause other pins do (even with `Pull=NOPULL`, and according to the manual, the reset state is `0x0` so that's what I'd expect, no? and yes I do see the status register being read correctly now that CLK is pulled low after GPIO init. I think it'd be a good takeaway at least to understand what could cause GPIO pin to be pulled low...

Comment: CPOL=1 would have been completely wrong mode for the radio chip. Clock must idle low so that first rising edge clocks in data to radio chip and MCU updates data on falling edge. SCK might have been pulled up by logic analyzer. Sure reset state for SCK output data is 0, but the pin would not be an output, or even an input, before initialized, and when initialized to AF_PP the data would not come from GPIO data register but from SPI peripheral that defines the state.

Comment: yeah true, but I meant in case CPOL=1 would've been fine for the chip. Sure, it's neither output nor an input but my question is why should it be pulled low (via `PULL=GPIO_PULLDOWN`) specifically?

Answer (score 0):

SPI has different "modes" based on when data must be stable with respect to the clock signal for sampling purposes. I bet you haven't configured the SPI driver for what your device expects for clock polarity and clock phase settings. These are commonly referred to as CPOL and CPHA in datasheets and literature on the topic. I'm just speculating though.